# I get NetworkOnMainThreadExeption when using kevinsawickis http-request class

Tags: android, httprequest

I am using https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request and I am trying to use one of the examples from it. This is my Android code:

```
try{
 String response = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com").body();
 System.out.println("Response was: " + response);
}
catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
 Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I get this error:
Android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExeption. And from my Android Monitor I get:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.nettport.dietbystram.dietbystram, PID: 11523
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SignUp}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1425)
>                                                                                             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
>                                                                                             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
>                                                                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
>                                                                                             at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:207)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:2093)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.HttpRequest.parameter(HttpRequest.java:2188)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.HttpRequest.charset(HttpRequest.java:2298)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.HttpRequest.body(HttpRequest.java:1758)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.SignUp.sendToPHP(SignUp.java:1529)
>                                                                                             at mypackage.SignUp.onCreate(SignUp.java:81)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Try to do this in background not on main thread

Comment: Use Asychtask for the same

Comment: Try to add your HttpRequest  in async task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the same in this

```
     private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           String response = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com").body();
 System.out.println("Response was: " + response);
            return response ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

Start it in your onCreate like this  new LongOperation().execute("");

Comment: Should I build a LongOperation for every thing I want to check?
Example LongOperationIsEmailTaken, LongOperationRegisterNewUser, LongOperationCheckLogin etc

Comment: There are example where you can make generic Asych task. You can google it for more results. Else If you think that anything which takes time and can be done in background should either be in asych task , services , threads or third party library such as Bolt : https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android